# Skill to represent understanding dead languages, not necessarily speaking them

Tags: skills, chronicles-of-darkness-1e

A character I'm creating is going to be an expert in ancient and dead languages, hopefully quite a few.

Is a linguistics speciality in Academics enough (so he can decode/translate ancient Sumerian manuscripts, etc., without being fluent in, say, conversational ancient Phoenician) or do I need to buy a language merit in each individual language? If I do this, it is going to get completely unfeasible merit point-wise very quickly.

Or is this something better off being covered by my ST?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what you've described, the "Ancient and Dead Languages" specialty for Academics should do just fine. If you have access to **The God-Machine Chronicle** update for **World of Darkness** ([the rules update is free](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/114078/World-of-Darkness-The-God-Machine-Rules-Update?term=god%20machine)), you might also ask to take the "Multilingual" merit (p.163) which allows you to take 2 languages at a lesser level for a single merit dot—and it can be taken multiple times.

Comment: Strange the GMC by my broke my pdf reader.